# How to get a list of days of a month with the 0?

Tags: c#

I'm trying to get a list of days for the current month, but the result is: `1, 2, 3, 4` etc.. I want something like: `01, 02, 03, 04` etc...

How can I do this?

This is the code I wrote:

```
int monthDays = DateTime.DaysInMonth(DateTime.Now.Year, DateTime.Now.Month);
var days = Enumerable.Range(1, monthDays).ToArray();
```

Comment: You have to use the correct formatting when displaying the `int` values.  Note the `int` does not contain formatting information like padding zeros.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should change the output to an array of strings if you want to see a leading zero on your numbers

```
var days = Enumerable.Range(1, monthDays).Select(x => x.ToString("D2")).ToArray();
```

And you can learn about the *D2* formatting reading [Standard Numeric Format Strings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-numeric-format-strings)

Comment: Ok, this is even simpler than my solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this with the `PadLeft` method:

```
var formattedDays = days.Select(day => day.ToString().PadLeft(2, '0'));
```